# BC109 to Drive a 75Ohms realy

Tags: transistors, relay

Transistors are always very confusing to me. I read and try to understand the specsheet always but never confident about my understanding :( I have PCB (readymade), which gives me a 2.8V output when I switch on the PCB. The 2.8V is coming out from the MCU directly. Now if I drive a BC109 with that output and put a 75ohms relay in a  common emitter fashion then will the transistor be able to supply enough current to turn on the relay? According to my calculation, the BC109 max collector current is 200mA and a 12V/75ohms relay will require around 160mA current. If I put an additional resistance in serial with the relay's coil, then I can bring down the current more. Can someone please tell me if I am theoretically all correct or not. I am not attaching any drawing as it is really a tiny circuit and can be visualized easily.

=======================================================

After reading the comments, here is the question in a more mathematical way. Please let me know if I understand it correct.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDZtBu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Transistor : BC337
Relay: 12V / 75 Ohms

Connection type: Common Emitter

Input Voltage (applied to base) = 2.8

Required Current to turn on the relay = 12V / 75 Ohms  = 160 mA

Max Ic = 800mA (Safe to drive the relay)

Current Gain to hard on BC337 = 10

Base current required to switch on the transistor (thus the relay) = (Current Gain / Load Current) = 160/10 = 16mA

Vbe = 0.7

Effecting Base Voltage = 2.8 - 0.7 = 2.1

Required base resistor = Vb / Ib = 2.1 / .016 = 131 Ohms (approx)

Transistor's power dissipation: (Vce * Ic) + (Vbe * Ib) = 196mW Approx

Comment: What's a collector follower? Do you mean a common collector?

Comment: @dirac16 Yes, that's correct

Comment: You cannot learn how to use a transistor by just staring at the datasheet. The datasheet is for engineers who already know what they want. What you need to do is look at **examples** how to use a transistor to drive a relay. Search for them on the internet or even this site. There's a list left right on this page on the right. Driving a 160mA relay with a 200 mA max transistor is pushing it though. Better use a 500 mA transistor. BC109 is also "stone age". Try a BC337

Comment: Well, you're still unsure about the correct name. In addition to what @Bimpelrekkie said I recommend you get a book and pick 100 questions or more (about BJTs, MOSFETS, etc) and solve them one by one. This is **the only way** to become confident in transistors or else.

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments and suggesting me to read about transistor. I came here because I needed someone to clarify me. You should understand that If I would get enough information from books and google, then I would not come here. I put down my mathematical understanding and now I want someone to find out if I understand it correctly or I am doing the math wrong.

Comment: BC109 emitter to ground. Collector to relay. Relay between collector and V+ (12V). Reverse diode across relay coil (essential) . Drive base much harder / more current than minimum suggested by current gain. Transistor will turn on harder and have less Vce drop. Limit is what drivce source happily supplies. Probably eg 330 R drive if load is acceptable to drive source

Comment: Hi @RussellMcMahon, I have edited the question and now I have my understanding of the maths behind the BJT. The transistor is changed to BC337. Can you look at the second part of the question and tell me if my calculations are correct.

Comment: @RakeshMehta: There is a schematic tool on the editor toolbar. If you draw a schematic we will all know exactly what you are describing and you will get good answers.

Comment: Calculations appear rightish. Beta of 10 is low but acceptable. 16 mA is too high for many mcus and odds are is nit needed here. Using a high beta BC337 eg BC337-40 ensures good Beta.

Comment: Hi @RussellMcMahon, thank you. Yes actually I was looking for higher beta. All of the blogs said use 10 as standard beta and I was confused. As you pointed, 16mA for MCU is too high. But if we can get a Beta of 40, then it will come down to 4mA and MCU will be happy. I'll check the BC337-40. Thank you again.